# Getting real screen resolution on Samsung Galaxy S7 in java or UE4 c++

Tags: java, android, c++, unreal-engine4

I'm trying to get the real resolution of the device, here it's Samsung Galaxy S7, but it doesn't work on SGS 6 also.

I've tried using Java's DisplayMetrics:

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
int width=dm.widthPixels;
int height=dm.heightPixels;
```

-this returns 1920x1080.

Tried Unreal Engine's:

```
FPlatformMisc::GetHardwareWindow()
GEngine->GameViewport->Viewport->GetSizeXY()
```

-both wrong.

The desired result is **2560x1440**. Any ideas?

Edit: I'm working on UE 4.10

Comment: Sounds strange. Try `getRealMetrics(dm)`

Comment: tried that too, it's the same

Answer (score 2):

I'm late, I know, but if someone is facing with this problem I solved with this:

```
Display display = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
scwidth = display.getMode().getPhysicalWidth();}
```

Comment: The correct answer is never late. Thanks you very much, it saved me tons of time.